# Does IIS / ARR rewrites one URL per line ONLY?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, arr

I have recently found out that, if there are multiple URLs (eligible for rewriting) in one line of a web page, the IIS / ARR would only rewrite the first match of that line, and ignore the rest.  So I'd like to ask two questions:

1. Is this the default behavior of the IIS / ARR URL rewriting function?
2. Is there any work-around for this behavior, such that the IIS / ARR could recognize -- and rewrite -- multiple URLs on the same line?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to ensure Regex doesn't match anything outside of the quotes, i.e. stop it from being greedy.

Using the GUI the match pattern ends with `([^"]*)` instead of `(.*)`, and when saved in the Web.config this gets escaped to `([^&quot;]*)`

The line in my Web.config looks like this:

```
<match filterByTags="None" pattern="http://your.domain/~/media([^&quot;]*)" />
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! In my case I was trying to write an outbound rule for substituting `href` in HTML content encoded in javascript (so something like `href=\"link\"`), and I had to change the rule from `<match filterByTags="None" pattern="href=\\\&quot;(.*)\\\&quot;" />` to `<match filterByTags="None" pattern="href=\\\&quot;([^\&quot;]*)\\\&quot;" />`, otherwise only the first occurrence of `href=\"link\"` on every line was substituted, due to `(.*)` being greedy and eating up all input text

Answer (score 0):

So I think it's safe to assume you're referring to an outbound rewrite rule to change URLs in HTML responses.

1. No that is not the default behaviour of the rewrite module.
2. Update your question to include your rule configuration so that we can help.

**Useful information:**

In your `<match>` element if you do not specify the `filterByTags`, then the match pattern will be applied on the **entire response content**, regardless of lines and occurrences. Note that the evaluation of regular expression patterns on the entire response content is a CPU intensive operation and may affect the performance of the web application.

It sounds to be that your rule(s) aren't properly configured.

**Further information:**

- [URL Rewrite Module 2.0 Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference)
- [Creating Outbound Rules for URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The problem is that, that configuration is done by the administrative staff and I am not authorized to dig into it.  Nevertheless, as far as I know, they just use the GUI to do configuration and have never dealt with any rule files (which I usually found on online resources)

Comment: I suggest that you gain a copy of the websites web.config file, add the rewrite rules yourself, test them out, and pass back the web.config file to your administrative staff. It's a pretty horrible situation of too'ing and fro'ing - I feel your pain.